# How to generate working .ics file from static website?

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I want to create a static html website with a calendar entry download function, it should work on new browsers (no need for IE).

First I tried out this js lib to create a `.ics` file: https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js - I couldn't get it to work...
Then I tried an adjusted fork, which I did get to create and download a file with: https://github.com/matthiasanderer/icsFormatter

I'm testing it on Windows 10 and it opened successfully in `MS Outlook` but then I noticed the file didn't open in the Windows calendar app:
The error translates to something like: `"The event couldn't be opened. Perhaps the calendar file is damaged."`
[image: Windows Calendar App Error Message]

---

In Safari on an iPhone an error also occurs when tapping the download button:
The error translates to something like: `"Safari can not load this file."`
[image: Safari error message]

---

I validated the generated `.ics` file with this tool: http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com/validate/ , adjusted the JS code to eliminate almost all errors - and I don't know if this last error, that I don't know how to get rid of, is essential:

```
Specifying the charset in the MIME Content-Type is mandatory
```

[image: Validation Error]
I thought the `MIME` type should not be the problem because it is defined in the JS-download function in this line:

```
window.open("data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8," + escape(calendar));
```

---

I also wonder why the download works fine in `Chrome` but `Firefox` (V.72) downloads the file with twice the file ending at the end: `.ics.ics`
[image: Double file ending]

---

And I wish I could give the file a name - but the only way that I found to do this was for .csv files in the bottom part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966131/4120196) and it didn't work - I think the `encodeURI` function destroyed my linebreaks or something.

---

This is the content of my generated .ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//test//cal_events/NONSGML v1.0//DE
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:b1e4da94-1550-453f-bdee-a085a0b14231
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:This is the description...
DTSTAMP:20200125T084646Z
DTSTART:20200229T190000z
DTEND:20200229T230000z
LOCATION:Deutschland
SUMMARY:Event Title
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

---

Looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7346619/4120196) is similar...

Comment: Maybe not related to the problem, but it should be `.ics`, not `.isc`.

Comment: @Barmar thx - I always get it mixed up, I corrected it - it was not related unfortunately :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both you DTSTART and DTEND have a lower case z as suffix instead of capital Z

```
DTSTART:20200229T190000z
DTEND:20200229T230000z
```

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5

> The date with UTC time, or absolute time, is identified by a LATIN
> CAPITAL LETTER Z suffix character, the UTC designator, appended to
> the time value.

Comment: Thx, the file works on an iPhone now, still not on the windows calendar app, but - what's weird - it's working on the windows calendar app on another pc. So I guess it's not the file's fault.